Как подключить стили карт к такому коду?
Как в таком случае к моему примеру правильно подключить стили генерируемые редактором стилей карт, потому что у меня их не подключает ни при каких условиях, хотя вроде бы всё верно, пользовался этим: map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({ customization: PASTE_JSON_HERE }));


let center = [59.68249328771387, 80.28810420751564];
ymaps.ready(init);
        function init(){
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: center,
                zoom: 2
            });
          
          let main = new ymaps.Placemark([55.796238068961486, 37.76556099999989], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Главный офис</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>105037, г Москва, проезд Измайловский, д. 5А, пом. 34H</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+74955104944">+7 (495) 510‑49-44</a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@sdmopt.com">info@sdmopt.com</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [42, 42],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let warehouse = new ymaps.Placemark([55.82353006891234, 37.78104749999992], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Складкской комплекс</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>г. Москва, 107497, ул. Иркутская д.17, стр. 8</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+74955104944">+7 (495) 510‑49-44</a>
                    <a href="tel:+74956603351">+7 (495) 660‑33-51</a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@sdmopt.com">info@sdmopt.com</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [32, 32],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let spb = new ymaps.Placemark([59.88791609656807, 30.325855173610595], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Санкт-Петербург</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>196084, ул. Коли Томчака д.20Б лит. В</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78123870671">+7 (812) 387-06-71</a>
                    <a href="mailto:schank@mail.ru">schank@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let kazan = new ymaps.Placemark([55.74847256898776, 49.1120105], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Казань</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>ООО “КОБРА-КАЗАНЬ”.</p>
                    <p>г.Казань, ул. Турбинная, 7</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78432586266">+7 (843) 258 62 66</a>
                    <a href="tel:+79872667244">+7 (987) 266 72 44</a>
                    <a href="tel:+79274325274">+7 (927) 432 52 74</a>
                    <a href="mailto:cobra-kazan@yandex.ru">cobra-kazan@yandex.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let krasnodar = new ymaps.Placemark([45.01330007458955, 38.995740499999954], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Краснодар</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>350001, ул. Вишняковой, 5/2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78612990505">+7 (861) 299-05-05</a>
                    <a href="mailto:89180989898@mail.ru">89180989898@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let ussuruisk = new ymaps.Placemark([43.792093074582596, 131.97923299999994], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Уссурийск</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>Олеся Кожемякина</p>
                    <p>Менеджер по продажам ООО «СДМ»</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+79146815702">+7(914) 681-57-02</a>
                    <a href="mailto:ussursdm@mail.ru">ussursdm@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });

    myMap.controls.remove('geolocationControl'); // удаляем геолокацию
    myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl'); // удаляем контроль трафика
    myMap.controls.remove('searchControl'); // удаляем поиск
    myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector'); // удаляем тип
    myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl'); // удаляем кнопку перехода в полноэкранный режим




Стилизация недоступна в JS API 2.1 и ниже. Для использования стилей из Редактора необходимо использовать JS API 3.0.

Да, я знаю, но насколько я понимаю, в данном примере использовано как раз 3.0, так как мне на это исправили 2 вопросами выше

Нет, это именно 2.1. Большая часть структуры кода была именно 2.1, потому и исправили на неё. Для 3.0 нужно писать новый код, опираясь на документацию и примеры.
